# PHP Get key value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the key from an array to make divs become:

```
<div id="item">
<div id="item-1">
<div id="item-2">
<div id="item-3">
```

My array code is:

```
$a = $something['no'];
$array = array_fill(0, $a, 'value');
foreach($array as $key => $value){
 if($key == '0') {
  $x = 'item';
 } else {
  $x = 'item-'.$key;
 }
 $insert .= '<div id="'.$x.'">';
  // content here
 $insert .= '</div>';
}
```

$key isn't being sent, I tried echoing $key and got no return, is there something I am missing?

Print_r on the array shows:

```
Array ( [0] => value [1] => value [2] => value )
```

Fixed Code:

```
$a = $something['no'];
$array = array_fill(0, $a, 'value');
foreach($array as $key => $value){
 if($key == '0') {
  $x = 'item';
 } else {
  $x = 'item-'.$key;
 }
 $insert .= '<div id="'.$insert = $x.'">';
  // content here
 $insert .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: let's `print_r` your `$array`

Comment: Nothing is being printed, I also tried var_dump

Comment: Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php). The second argument of array_fill function should be a integer. Is it?

Comment: Yes it is as the foreach is spitting out the right number of divs but without the end $key

Comment: oops just realised it was printing, the contents are in the main post (it was hidden by something in my theme).

Comment: "$key isn't being sent" What does this mean? What do you see? Inputs and outputs please.

Comment: Just been messing with the code and I cannot get $value or $Key to echo in the foreach, something is messing this up

Comment: Well, we can't see what, because [the code you posted does not exhibit the problem](http://codepad.org/3Pdm3Nlw).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I fixed it (will add code above), basically I wasn't putting $insert = $x so it wasn't sending it to the function to be spitted out.

Comment: @Gareth: Eh? Why are you breaking working code? I just demonstrated that your code was correct (and therefore your problem is somewhere else, that you didn't show us). `$insert .= '<div id="'.$insert = $x.'">';` is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could minimize your code with a `for` loop:

```
$something['no'] = 4;

$html = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $something['no']; $i++) {
  $x = !$i ? '' : "-{$i}";
  $content = "woof woof";
  $html .= "<div id=\"item{$x}\">".$content."</div>\n";
}
print_r($html);
```

Saves on assigning a variable and running a separate process to fill an array with numbers which you could just add up to anyway